# Why am I getting the following error message?

Tags: python, function, dictionary, return-value

The defined function will return the altered dictionary.
The parameter 'teams' is a dictionary and the parameter 'driver' is a string. The key of 'teams' is the driver and its value is the other team member. So I am trying to swap the 'driver' from the input parameter and the other team member:

```
 def switch(teams, driver):
        temp = teams[driver]
        switch[temp] = driver
        del switch[driver]
        return teams

    print(switch({'Jack':'Jill', 'Romeo':'Juliet', 'Drake':'Josh'}, 'Drake'))
```

Why am I getting the following error message? Where in the code am I going wrong?

switch[temp] = driver
TypeError: 'function' object does not support item assignment

Comment: what are you trying to do at this line `switch[temp] = driver`

Comment: `switch` is a function, so `switch[temp]` is meaningless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stay consistent with your method:

1. Pick the value out of the dictionary that's gonna be the new key
2. Add the new entry to the dictionary
3. Remove the old entry

```
    def switch(teams, driver):
       temp = teams[driver]
       teams[temp] = driver
       del teams[driver]
       return teams
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I didn't realize I was adding the new entry to the function instead of the dictionary which makes absolutely no sense. A very stupid mistake. Thanks again!

Comment: Happy to help! Please accept the answer if you're happy with it - this keeps the forum focused on unanswered questions.